Does Google PageSpeed Insights use any sort of unusual caching?
I've been optimizing a website lately and the results of PageSpeed Insights left me confused multiple times. Examples:

I decreased a 2 MB .webm video down to ~700 KB on desktop and ~300 KB on mobile, also ensured that only one file is loaded. That made 0 difference for the rating for few days when I checked - it was still around ~20 on mobile and ~60 on desktop.
Decreasing the size of bunch of .webp/.avif images by 30-50% also didn't help.
I moved to Cloudflare from a hosting that apparently uses Cloudflare underneath. That somehow changed the mobile rating to ~50 and left desktop at ~60.

I'm mostly confused at the asset optimization not doing anything according to the tests. I also used Pingdom test + other less popular tools and the rating logically improved there.
Does PageSpeed Insights use some strong caching? Or does it also maybe heavily rely on some visitor data? Otherwise, why did it ignore those changes, while other tools didn't?

Pagespeed Insights uses two metrics:

Discover what your real users are experiencing
Diagnose performance issues

The first one is not a real-time measurement. It's a cached version of several hundred (thousands?) visitors to your site from 28 days. Source.
In addition, sometimes it doesn't have enough information for your particular URL, so it shows the aggregate version from the whole site.
The second one is a real-time measurement of your page. That's the one you should focus on.

Thanks. How does it mix both ratings? From how many days/months are the rating stored/collected? Any source link would also be great for accepting it as final answer.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about - cache experiences over the previous 28-day collection period

The results are not mixed. You get one set of KPIs for real-world experience averages, and another for the actual result you are testing

Oh ok, so the upper 5 stats are from 28 days and the lower 4 ratings from the session? Kind of confusing UI. But it makes sense as the lower ones are much more dynamic. Still weird that the lower ones didn't improve when reducing the asset download size by a lot.
